# Linux tar files within specific date range using filename date

Tags: linux, shell, date, globbing

I have files whose names begin with YYYYMMDD like the following:

```
20160221_143223_Report.csv
20160222_121223_Report.csv
           ...
20160229_141223_Report.csv
20160301_171223_Report.csv
```

I want to tar files that have "Report" in filename and whose names correspond to the range 1-8 days ago.  For example: today is 1st of March, so I want to tar files from 22th Feb to 29th Feb (today not inclusive).

```
files=($(ls |<HAS "Report" in filename> and  <WITHIN `date -d "8 days ago" '+%Y%m%d'> )) #output will be filenames that has the word "Report" and  from 22th to 29th FEB
tar cvfz oldfile.tar.gz "${files[@]}"
```

What is the pattern that I should match?

Comment: Did you read the man page for tar? It has a newer option... find does too, plus regex and !

Comment: Does the modification date of the file match the date in the filename?

Comment: @Paul Yes it is the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find` is probably the best bet if you want to run it yourself:

```
find . -name '*Report.csv' -mtime +8 | xargs  tar -czvf  oldfile.tar.gz
```

There is also a pretty standard tool for clearing up old files called `logrotate` which can match a pattern in a folder and do various tidyups, including compressing old files and deleting historics.